# transferring files between directories

Tags: bash, file, directory

I have a directory called `mdamb231(data_and_results)` on the server and I want to transfer some files from this directory to another one, but since the name is weird it gives this error:

```
"-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('".
```

I tried to change the name using `mv` command but got the same error.
do you guys know how to transfer my files from this directory?

Comment: Escape the `()`:  `mdamb231\(data_and_results\)` or put the file name in single quotes: `'mdamb231(data_and_results)'`. `bash` can help you escape awkward filenames using file name completion (type the first characters then press the `tab` key).

Answer (score 1):

You need to put backslashes before the brackets to escape them, i.e.

`mv mdamb231\(data_and_results\) newfilename`

or put the file path in single quotes

`mv 'mdamb231(data_and_results)' newfilename`